# java.rmi.MarshalException , how to fix it ?!

Tags: java, rmi

hi there i'm using netbeans to write  RMI Client and server program .

i used a class (call SoundBuffer ) used in Jsfml lib

and when trying to send an object of it i get this :

```
SEVERE: null
java.rmi.MarshalException: error marshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
        java.io.NotSerializableException: org.jsfml.audio.SoundBuffer
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:156)
        at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:194)
        at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:148)
        at $Proxy0.rsound(Unknown Source)
        at rmicallback.Client1ap.jButton5ActionPerformed(Client1ap.java:238)
        at rmicallback.Client1ap.access$400(Client1ap.java:30)
        at rmicallback.Client1ap$5.actionPerformed(Client1ap.java:113)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6504)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6269)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4860)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4686)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2713)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4686)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:707)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:680)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:678)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:677)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.jsfml.audio.SoundBuffer
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1180)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.marshalValue(UnicastRef.java:292)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:151)
        ... 42 more

Exception while removing reference: java.lang.InterruptedException
java.lang.InterruptedException
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:135)
        at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:151)
        at sun.java2d.Disposer.run(Disposer.java:145)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

when i try to call a method in server that take a parameter type SoundBuffer

like this :

```
 try {
            //org is type SoundBuffer 
            si.rsound(org, tag);
        } catch (RemoteException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Client1ap.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

as i knew that it is because of soundbuffer class is not serialized so how i can make it like that , or how can i serialize the object (org type soundbuffer )

please tell me how to do that .... and thanks .

Answer (score 0):

If you can't alter the class to make it Serializable, you will have to use something else that is. The raw data for example.